# ¿Cómo comparar columnas de tablas diferentes en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estoy trabajando en MySQL y tengo que comparar dos columnas (`Total` y `PagoAbono`) de diferentes tablas, una llamada por ejemplo `Historial` y otra `Pagos`. En la de pagos está el campo `Total` y en la tabla de historial tengo un campo que se llama `PagosAbono`.

En la tabla `Pagos` solo hay un "Folio" con un `Total` y en la tabla `Historial` hay varios "Folios" repetidos con `PagosAbono`.

Tengo que sumar todos los folios usando `SUM(PagosAbono)` y obtener un solo Folio y su  total. Si la suma de esos folios de la tabla `Historial` es menor al total del mismo folio en la tabla `Pagos` (o no están), entonces tengo que mostrarlos ya que asumo que aún me deben.

Tengo este ejemplo de código, pero no me da el resultado que busco.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Pagos A
       INNER JOIN Historial B 
       ON ((SUM(B.PagosAbono) < A.Total) and (A.Folio = B.Folio))
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no entendí mal tu pregunta, podrías resolverlo con una subconsulta, es decir, en primer lugar obtenemos el total de `Historial.PagosAbono` por `Folio` y está consulta es la que vincularemos con `Pagos`, mediante un `LEFT JOIN` ya que cabría la posibilidad de no tener registros en `Historial` e imagino que igual quisieras verlos.

```
SELECT *
       from Pagos A
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Folio,
                         SUM(PagosAbono) AS 'PagosAbono'
                         FROM Historial
                         GROUP BY Folio
              ) B
              ON A.Folio = B.Folio
       WHERE IFNULL(B.PagosAbono,0) < A.Total
```

Comment: Exactamente como lo describes es lo que quiero hacer, poro tomando tu ejemplo no funciona. La subconsulta si me trae todos los folios y sus pagos como los quiero, pero al comparar con la tabla de pagos marca error en el where, si pongo el where asi como tu me dice Recuento de parámetros incorrectos en la llamada a la función nativa 'ISNULL'.  Ya intente quitandolo y me dice que B.PagosAbono es una columna desconocida.

Comment: Es que estoy en modo sqlserver, `ISNULL` no existe en mysql, hay que cambiarla por `IFNULL`, pruebalo, cualquier cosa me dices

Comment: Ya habia realizado el cambio pero me dice que la columna B.PagosAbono es desconocida en la clausula Where

Comment: Había un alias de mas dentro de la subconsulta, editado

Comment: si el alias no estaba dentro del where pero lo puse y este me mado los datos esperado, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías tener una consulta en `Pagos` con una columna cuyo valor será el resultado de una subconsulta para sumar los pagos abonados para el folio correspondiente a ese Pago.

```
SELECT P.folio,
       P.total,
       IFNULL((SELECT SUM(pagosabono) FROM Historial H WHERE H.folio = P.folio),0) AS abonado
FROM   Pagos P
HAVING P.total > abonado;
```

Esa consulta devolverá 3 campos: el folio, el total a pagar de ese folio, y la cantidad abonada hasta el momento para ese folio según el Historial. Ten en cuenta que, al ser `abonado` una columna calculada/agregada, en lugar de usar `WHERE` se debe usar `HAVING`.

Puedes verla funcionando en este [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f01b5/1).

Comment: Probe tu sugerencia y tambien es util gracias.